# Passing URL Parameter from one state to another state in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working with Angularjs for my current project. I am passing a parameter from one state to another. Getting correctly. But whenever I refresh the page, that parameter is returned as null. Here is my working code. Routing part and home controller and trainer controller.

```
.state('search.trainer', {
     params: {'ind_array': null},
     url: '/trainer',
     templateUrl: 'tpl/trainer.search.html',
     resolve: {         
       deps: ['uiLoad',
       function (uiLoad) {
     return uiLoad.load(['js/controllers/trainerCtrl.js']);
                         }],
     ind_array: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
                 return $stateParams.ind_array;
          }],
       },
     controller: "trainerctrl",
       });
myApp.controller('homectrl', function( $scope, $state, $stateParams) {
       if($scope.search=="trainers"){
     $state.go('search.trainer', { ind_array : $scope.Selectdid});
     }
});

    myApp.controller('trainerctrl', function( $scope, $state, $stateParams, ind_array) {

        console.log(ind_array);

    });
```

Comment: Can you encode the parameter in the URL itself? lets say: `url: '/trainer/:trainer_id'`

Comment: @Paulo I also, tried. above you mentioned, using like above.. my  page is redirected but, URL was unchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not storing your "last state" in **localStorage or rather sessionStorage**? And when you load the page, if the value is null, fetch it from localStorage and restore the view state.

**UPDATE**:

1) each time you get the last state version, just do a window.localStorage.setItem('myLastState', state);

2) when you load the app and there's no state, window.localStorage.getItem('myLastState') should provide you what you need

On **first load** you would need to provide some defaults for those states.

Comment: I never worked with localStorage/sessionStorage Can You please guide me how to implement with localStorage/sessionStorage

Comment: It's very simple. **sessionStorage** are basically the same, the only difference is that localStorage keeps data even after you close the browser while sessionStorage "expires" when you close it.

For the usage itself, see updated answer.